# Http error when calling the duckduckgo api

Tags: python, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am currently following a course on machine learning : the course from the fast.ai web site.
The course is a video, but it is linked to a a jupyter notebook on  kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/code/jhoward/is-it-a-bird-creating-a-model-from-your-own-data). However when i try to run cell number 11: the one that contains this code:

```
#NB: `search_images` depends on duckduckgo.com, which doesn't always return correct responses.
#    If you get a JSON error, just try running it again (it may take a couple of tries).
urls = search_images('bird photos', max_images=1)
urls[0]
```

I get this error :

```
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_17/2432147335.py in <module>
      1 #NB: `search_images` depends on duckduckgo.com, which doesn't always return correct responses.
      2 #    If you get a JSON error, just try running it again (it may take a couple of tries).
----> 3 urls = search_images('bird photos', max_images=1)
      4 urls[0]

/tmp/ipykernel_17/3153793264.py in search_images(term, max_images)
      4 def search_images(term, max_images=30):
      5     print(f"Searching for '{term}'")
----> 6     return ddg_images(term, max_results=max_images).itemgot('image')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/duckduckgo_search/compat.py in ddg_images(keywords, region, safesearch, time, size, color, type_image, layout, license_image, max_results, page, output, download)
     80         type_image=type_image,
     81         layout=layout,
---> 82         license_image=license_image,
     83     ):
     84         results.append(r)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/duckduckgo_search/duckduckgo_search.py in images(self, keywords, region, safesearch, timelimit, size, color, type_image, layout, license_image)
    403         assert keywords, "keywords is mandatory"
    404 
--> 405         vqd = self._get_vqd(keywords)
    406         assert vqd, "error in getting vqd"
    407 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/duckduckgo_search/duckduckgo_search.py in _get_vqd(self, keywords)
     93     def _get_vqd(self, keywords: str) -> Optional[str]:
     94         """Get vqd value for a search query."""
---> 95         resp = self._get_url("POST", "https://duckduckgo.com", data={"q": keywords})
     96         if resp:
     97             for c1, c2 in (

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/duckduckgo_search/duckduckgo_search.py in _get_url(self, method, url, **kwargs)
     87                 logger.warning(f"_get_url() {url} {type(ex).__name__} {ex}")
     88                 if i >= 2 or "418" in str(ex):
---> 89                     raise ex
     90             sleep(3)
     91         return None

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/duckduckgo_search/duckduckgo_search.py in _get_url(self, method, url, **kwargs)
     80                 )
     81                 if self._is_500_in_url(str(resp.url)) or resp.status_code == 202:
---> 82                     raise httpx._exceptions.HTTPError("")
     83                 resp.raise_for_status()
     84                 if resp.status_code == 200:

HTTPError:
```

I tried running all the cells above, successfully : my Kaggle account is verified and I have enabled internet.
I suspect that the duckduckgo.com website does not work (because the error thrown is inside an if statement , and that statement is verified if the Http response code contains a 500) : is there a way for me to check if this is the case only for me or for everyone else, if so : does anyone of have found a way to bypass this problem and still finish lesson one of the course?

Comment: You cut the trace output just before the actual error, it would help to provide the end of that error log. Also, did you try a few times like it says in the comments, and do you always get the same response?

Comment: No this is the whole error , is outputs the empty string , and you can see it in the last piece of code of the call stack : raise httpx._exceptions.HTTPError("") .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. On the right side of the webpage, under "Notebook options", find a
   drop down menu called "ENVIRONMENT".
2. Change this to "Always use latest environment".
3. Rerun ALL the cells (including the cell with the import statement) and see if the error persists.

Answer (score 1):

When I had this error, I also had an accompanying warning that use of 'ddg_images' is deprecated. Reading the duckduckgo_search documentation, https://pypi.org/project/duckduckgo-search/

I got it to working by modifying the search_images() function.

```
from duckduckgo_search import DDGS
from fastcore.all import *

ddgs = DDGS()
def search_images(term, max_images=30):
    print(f"Searching for '{term}'")
    return L(ddgs.images(term, max_results=max_images)).itemgot('image')
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue last night and I came to find out that by copying the notebook duckduckgo_search was set to v3.8.5 and Jeremy Howard's notebook must've had an older version than that since ddg_images is deprecated now.

By making the notebook yourself and after pip installing duckduckgo_search, you can verify the version by doing `!pip show duckduckgo-search` and at the time of writing this duckduckgo_search is v4.5.0.

Arjun Radha Krishnan's answer looks more concise, but I made mine using what I found in the docs (https://pypi.org/project/duckduckgo-search/)

```
from duckduckgo_search import DDGS
from fastcore.all import *

def search_images(term, max_images=30):
    print(f"Searching for: {term}")
    with DDGS() as ddgs:
        ddgs_images_gen = ddgs.images(term, max_results=max_images)
        results = list(ddgs_images_gen)
        return L(results).itemgot('image')
```

Hope this helps!